Generate OAuth2 accesstoken using grant-type- client_credentials when resource is passed
The below code for FeignClientConfiguration works fine if resource is not part of it. Could you please let me know on how to generate the access token if resource[Refer 2nd one] is passed along with client_id, client_secret, token_uri and grant_type using RequestInterceptor. I cannot use RestTemplate or WebClient.
I am using JDK8.
Error while posting request with access token passed in header: {"error":{"code":"InvalidAuthenticationTokenAudience","message":"The access token has been obtained for wrong audience or resource '00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'. It should exactly match with one of the allowed audiences 'management.core.windows.net/','https://…."}}
1. When resource not passed, working fine.
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class ClientConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public RequestInterceptor oauthFeignRequestInterceptor(ClientCredentialsResourceDetails resourceDetails) {
        OAuth2FeignRequestInterceptor requestInterceptor = new OAuth2FeignRequestInterceptor(new DefaultOAuth2ClientContext(), resourceDetails);
        requestInterceptor.setAccessTokenProvider(new ClientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider());
        return requestInterceptor;
    }

    @Bean
    public ClientCredentialsResourceDetails resourceDetails(@Value("${test.oauth.client-id}") String username,
                                                            @Value("${test.oauth.client-secret}") String password,
                                                            @Value("${test.oauth.tokenUri}") String tokenUri) {
        ClientCredentialsResourceDetails resourceDetails = new ClientCredentialsResourceDetails();
        resourceDetails.setAccessTokenUri(tokenUri);
        resourceDetails.setClientId(username);
        resourceDetails.setClientSecret(password);
        return resourceDetails;
    }
}

2. When resource is passed, access token is generated but without considering resource. Used https://jwt.io/ to check is its considering the resource which I am passing. Got to know that its not considering.

@Bean
    public CustomClientCredentialsResourceDetails resourceDetails(@Value("${apim.oauth2.grant-type}") String grantType,
                                                                  @Value("${apim.oauth2.access-token-uri}") String url,
                                                                  @Value("${apim.oauth2.client-id}") String clientId,
                                                                  @Value("${apim.oauth2.client-secret}") String clientSecret,
                                                                  @Value("${apim.oauth2.resource}") String resource) {
        CustomClientCredentialsResourceDetails resourceDetails = new CustomClientCredentialsResourceDetails();
        resourceDetails.setGrantType(grantType);
        resourceDetails.setAccessTokenUri(url);
        resourceDetails.setClientId(clientId);
        resourceDetails.setClientSecret(clientSecret);
        resourceDetails.setResource(resource);
        System.out.println("CustomClientCredentialsResourceDetails resourceDetails : "+resourceDetails.getResource());
        return resourceDetails;
    }

# jwt.io,
{
  "aud": "00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000", //Not considering resource.
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/0gt657j7yf/"
}

